# Laravel 5.1 Filter query

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel 5.1 project.
I'm making a filter option to display project results.

There is a input filter to seach by name
And a select for project status

The request is made by a AjaxRequest to a method Filter in a controller.
In this filter method i receive the array with the filter options

```
Array
(
    [filterName] => projectNameHere...
)
```

This is when the user only filters it by project name

And this is the array when the user search by projectname and status

```
Array
(
    [filterName]  => projectNameHere...
    [selectValue] => projectStatusHere
)
```

But now i need to create a dynamic select query for this. I have tried the following things:

```
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM project';
    $cond   = array();
    $params = array();

    if (array_key_exists('filterName', $request->all()))
    {
        $cond[]   = 'naam LIKE = %?%';
        $params[] = $request->filterName;
    }

    if (array_key_exists('selectValue', $request->all()))
    {
        $cond[]   = 'project_status = ?';
        $params[] = $request->selectValue;
    }

    // Implode the query
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $cond);
```

Also tried it with Laravel Raw select query::

```
$projects = DB::select('select * from project where name = ? AND project_status = ?', ['projectName', 'projectStats']);
```

This raw query works but how could i make it dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With laravel you can avoid writing too much sql. First some assumptions.

1. You have model called "Project" for the projects table
2. the array is extracted from the input sent by client.

Example:

```
public function performSearch(Request $req) {

   //create a new query builder (true to ignore deleted)
   $query = Project::query();

   if($req->has('filterName')) {
      $query = $query->where('filterName','like','%'.$req->input('filterName').'%');
   }

   if($req->has('selectValue')) {
      $query = $query->where('project_status ','=',$req->input('selectValue'));
   }

   //execute
   $results = $query->get();
}
```

the `$query` will be constructed based on the values present

Comment: When using  
 //create a new query builder (true to ignore deleted)
 $query = Project::newQuery(true); 

I get the following error: Non-static method 'newQuery' should not be called statically less... 
Dynamic class method called as static.

Comment: @Bham sorry my mistake, i believe it should be correct now according to [here](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_query)